# vertx decide on jsonobject vs jsonarray

Tags: arrays, json, vert.x

I am writing a framework level code for a Vert.x implementation which runs like an "interceptor" before all the api calls get to their corresponding handlers in their verticles.

As this "interceptor" runs for each API call, it needs to handle all kinds of Json requests:

1. Ones that have just a single JsonObject:

```
{
   "fname":"John",
   "lname":"Cena"
}
```

2. One's with JsonArray's:

```
    [
      {
        "fname":"John",
        "lname":"Cena"
      },
      {
        "fname":"Shawn",
        "lname":"Michaels"
      }
    ]
```

Based on the input, I want to decide, **should I parse the requestBody as a JsonObject or JsonArray**. Everything about the request parsing like the headers, query parameters, path parameters stay the same. 
 I know I can do something like:

```
public static int decideObjectOrArray(String requestBody) {
    Object json = new JSONTokener(requestBody).nextValue();
    if(json instanceof JSONObject) {
       return 1;
    }
    //you have an object
    else if(json instanceof JSONArray) {
      return 2;
    }
    //you have an array
    return 0;
}
```

But this needs the following new dependency in my pom:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

Can I not achieve the same behavior using the native vertx json packages?

- Another way I can think of achieving this to look at the 1st non-whitespace character in the requestBody and decide accordingly. But just doesn't seem like the cleanest way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Vert.x `JsonParser` to determine the type of content:

```
private Object parse(Buffer buffer) {
  JsonParser parser = JsonParser.newParser();
  AtomicReference<Object> result = new AtomicReference<>();
  parser.handler(event -> {
    switch (event.type()) {
      case VALUE:
        Object res = result.get();
        if (res == null) {
          result.set(event.value());
        } else if (res instanceof List) {
          List list = (List) res;
          list.add(event.value());
        } else if (res instanceof Map) {
          Map map = (Map) res;
          map.put(event.fieldName(), event.value());
        }
        break;
      case START_ARRAY:
        result.set(new ArrayList());
        parser.objectValueMode();
        break;
      case START_OBJECT:
        result.set(new HashMap());
        parser.objectValueMode();
        break;
    }
  });
  parser.handle(buffer);
  parser.end();
  Object res = result.get();
  if (res instanceof List) {
    return new JsonArray((List) res);
  }
  if (res instanceof Map) {
    return new JsonObject((Map<String, Object>) res);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Then if you invoke this method with different type of contents:

```
parsed = jsonTest.parse(Buffer.buffer("[1,2,3]"));
System.out.println(parsed.getClass().getName() + " : " + parsed);
System.out.println();
parsed = jsonTest.parse(Buffer.buffer("{\"hello\": \"world\"}"));
System.out.println(parsed.getClass().getName() + " : " + parsed);
System.out.println();
parsed = jsonTest.parse(Buffer.buffer("\"text\""));
System.out.println(parsed.getClass().getName() + " : " + parsed);
```

You'd get the result with the appropriate class:

```
io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray : [1,2,3]

io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject : {"hello":"world"}

java.lang.String : text
```

This is just an example of course, you would need to test the result object with `instanceof`.

**EDIT**: if you want to avoid the streaming parser (which might be slower), you could use the Jackson API directly:

```
private Object parse(Buffer buffer) {
  Object value;
  try {
    value = Json.mapper.readValue(buffer.getBytes(), Object.class);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
  if (value instanceof List) {
    List list = (List) value;
    return new JsonArray(list);
  } else if (value instanceof Map) {
    Map map = (Map) value;
    return new JsonObject(map);
  }
  return value;
}
```

You would get the same results.

**EDIT 2**: A [method has been added](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/2864) to `Buffer` to parse the content to JSON. It will be released in the next Vert.x version (3.7).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should operate on the `Buffer`, not on a `String` when working with body.
When working with `Buffer`, you have `toJsonArray()` and `toJsonObject()` to work with.
Although skipping through buffer in search of first `[` or `{` is also a valid option.

Comment: Point taken. If I work with a Buffer, I still need to figure out if I should call ```toJsonArray()``` or ```toJsonObject()```. If the input is a json object and I call ```toJsonArray()``` on it, I will get an exception. Similarly if the input is a json array and I call ```toJsonObject()``` on it, I will get an exception. I can handle these and then decide but doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Comment: If your concern is performance of exceptions (rarely an issue, actually) then you can take skipping through buffer approach.